# How to extract the phrase using the start and end phrases in this string?

Tags: python, regex

The string is the following:

```
string = '''Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]),
Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3])'''
```

I need to extract all the phrases starting with 'Node' and ending with '…..Id: 1.1.1].
eg: **`Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]`**
How can I use regex to do this?

This is my code:

`re.findall(r'^Node.]$',string)`

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to extract? Please give an example.

Comment: @alani I edited the post with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use:

```
inp = "Unit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]),\nUnit Id: 4, Section: 0 (Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3])"
matches = re.findall(r'\bNode Id: \d+ \[Consequence Id: \d+\.\d+\.\d+\]', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]', 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]', 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]', 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]', 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]', 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]', 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3]']
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any idea why the ^ and $ don't work in ```re.findall(r'^Node.]$',string)``` , given that they are indications for starting point and ending point in regular expressions

Comment: @PasinduSamaranayake They would try to anchor your regex to the start and end of the whole string. (Or at least the line. If you have a multiline string then there are different options available. Not relevant here.)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the example always using three components in the consequence ID, I am allowing here for it to contain any number of levels of dot-separated digits, e.g. 1 or 1.1 or 1.1.1 or 1.1.1.1.

Based on this, you can use:

```
re.findall('Node.*?Id: (?:\d+\.)*\d+\]', string)
```

Note the `.*?` matches any characters but as few as possible.

The `(?:\d+\.)*\d+` will match sequence of dot-separated numbers. It includes non-capturing parentheses (see the `?:`) so that the use of parentheses does not cause the bracket expression to affect the grouping used by `findall`.

Output:

```
['Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.1]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.3]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.1.2]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.1]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.2]',
 'Node Id: 2 [Consequence Id: 1.2.3]']
```